# Error in generation queen spatial weigth matrix

Tags: python, spatial, geopandas, pysal

I tried to generate a queen spatial weight matrix with pysal to calculate Moran's I.
The shapefile used is [here](ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/Brasil/BR/) , called br_unidades_da_federacao.

I executed the code

`w = ps.queen_from_shapefile('BRUFE250GC_SIR.shp')`

but received an error message that 3 observations were islands ( no neighbors): ids 0, 19 and 24.

I plotted the shapefile and marked the observations with the id to show that it is not islands.

id 0 and id 19 has 2 neighboors and id 24 has 3 neighboors.

The image is below[image]

What is wrong in the code?